# How do I deal with non-static members inside of an intent?

Tags: java, android, static

I'm having a tremendous amount of difficulty dealing with static members while trying to make an Android app.

Here's what the app has to do:

There are two tabs, My Classes and Class List, each of which are separate intents. The point of the app is that when you click the "add" button next to a class in the Class List, it should dynamically update the list under My Classes. However, I can't do this because my data structure that holds the classes is dynamic, but the Class List intent is static, so I keep getting the "Cannot reference non-static member from static context" error.

Is there any way to use dynamic intents, and if so, how?

EDIT:

Here's where the intents are declared:

```
public class TabLayout extends TabActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyClasses.class);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("My Classes")
                .setIndicator("My Classes", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_main))
                .setContent(intent));

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, ClassList.class);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Class List")
                .setIndicator("Class List", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_main))
                .setContent(intent2));

        Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, SyncList.class);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Sync List")
                .setIndicator("Sync List", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_main))
                .setContent(intent3));

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        // Set tabs Colors
        tabHost.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    }
}
```

Here's the MyClassList file:

public class MyClassList extends MyClasses {

```
int numClasses;
MyClasses myclasses = new MyClasses();
final static TableRow tableRowArray[] = new TableRow[4];
TextView classNameArray[] = new TextView[4];
TextView teacherNameArray[] = new TextView[4];
Button dropButtonArray[] = new Button[4];

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create containers
    ScrollView classListScrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    TableLayout classListTableLayout = new TableLayout(this); 

    // Add class entries
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        tableRowArray[i] = new TableRow(this);
        tableRowArray[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        classNameArray[i] = new TextView(this);
        classNameArray[i].setText("");
        classNameArray[i].setPadding(10, 20, 10, 20);
        classNameArray[i].setTextSize(20);
        tableRowArray[i].addView(classNameArray[i]);

        teacherNameArray[i] = new TextView(this);
        teacherNameArray[i].setText("");
        teacherNameArray[i].setPadding(10, 20, 10, 20);
        teacherNameArray[i].setTextSize(16);
        tableRowArray[i].addView(teacherNameArray[i]);

        dropButtonArray[i] = new Button(this);
        dropButtonArray[i].setText("Drop");
        tableRowArray[i].addView(dropButtonArray[i]);

        classListTableLayout.addView(tableRowArray[i], new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        tableRowArray[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    classListScrollView.addView(classListTableLayout);
    this.setContentView(classListScrollView);

    dropButtonArray[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            myclasses.dropClass(0);
        }
    });
    dropButtonArray[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            myclasses.dropClass(1);
        }
    });
    dropButtonArray[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            myclasses.dropClass(2);
        }
    });
    dropButtonArray[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            myclasses.dropClass(3);
        }
    });

}

public void updateMyClasses(ClassObject myclasses[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (myclasses[i].isNull)
        {
            classNameArray[i].setText(myclasses[i].getClassName());
            teacherNameArray[i].setText(myclasses[i].getTeacherName());
            tableRowArray[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            tableRowArray[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}

public MyClasses getMyClasses()
{
    return myclasses;
}
```

}

Here's the MyClasses file:

public class MyClasses extends Activity {

```
static int numClasses;
static ClassObject MyClassArray[];

public MyClasses()
{   
    MyClassArray = new ClassObject[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        MyClassArray[i] = new ClassObject();
    }

    numClasses = 0;
}

public int getNumClasses()
{
    return numClasses;
}

public void dropClass(int c)
{
    for (int i = c; i < 3; i++)
    {
        MyClassArray[i] = MyClassArray[i+1];
    }

    //MyClassList.updateMyClasses(MyClassArray);
}

public void addClass(ClassObject c)
{
    if (numClasses >= 4)
        return;

    MyClassArray[numClasses] = c;

    //MyClassList.updateMyClasses(MyClassArray);
}


public boolean hasClass(ClassObject c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (MyClassArray[i].getClassName() == c.getClassName())
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

And here's the line that gives the error:

```
addButtonArray[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                MyClasses.addClass(ClassListArray[0]);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why not just create the intent each time the button is pressed, and remove the static keyword in front of the global Intent variable.

Comment: Please paste here the part of the code that is giving you trouble

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
MyClasses.addClass(ClassListArray[0]);
```

You are trying to call the instance method `addClass` without giving the reference to a `MyClasses` instance.  How you fix this depends on where the code is.  Is it embedded in the `MyClasses` class?

Comment: I just added the code for MyClassList. Basically I tried to separate the GUI elements from the actual MyClasses data structure, but I still get the problem of trying to reference a non-static member (i.e. the MyClasses data structure) from a static context (i.e. the ClassList instance.)